# What's a good notation for an endomorphism induced on the quotient?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

For example, suppose that $V$ is a vector space, $A \in \operatorname{End}V$, and $U \subset V$ is an $A$-invariant subspace, and $\pi_{V/U}: V \to V/U$ the natural projection. Then $A$ induces a unique operator $\hat{A} \in \operatorname{End}(V/U)$ such that $\pi_{V/U} \circ A = \hat{A} \circ \pi_{V/U}$. Is there a generally accepted notation for $\hat{A}$?